# Unable to redirect from views.py

Tags: python, django

I want to redirect my url through views.py to an HTML page(Chatbot.html).
Below is the code which I am using .

I can see it is going inside if statement and giving me error
**errorSyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0**

Below is my views.py code

```
from django.shortcuts import render,get_object_or_404,render_to_response  
from django.http import HttpResponse  
import json  
from django.views.generic import TemplateView  
from django.views import View  
from .forms import HomeForm  
from django.http import JsonResponse  
from .models import Employee  
    class Login(View):  
        def post(self,request,*args,**kwargs):  
            response_data={}  
            response_data['email']= request.POST['email']  
            response_data['password']= request.POST['password']  
            data = Employee.objects.all()         
            for emp in data:  
                emailid = emp.usr_email  
                passkey = emp.usr_password   
                if emailid == request.POST['email'] and emp.usr_password == request.POST['password']:  
                    return render(request,'bot/chatbot.html')  
                else:  
                    return HttpResponse(json.dumps(response_data),  content_type="application/json")
```

here is my ajax code

```
$.ajax({  
                  type: "POST",  
                  url: "/bot/login/",  
                  dataType: "json",  
                  async: true,  
                  data:{  
                      csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}',  
                      email: email,  
                      password: password  
                  },  
                  success: function(json){  

                  },  
                  error : function(request, status, error) {  
                      var val = request.responseText;  
                      alert("error"+error);  
                  }  
                });
```

Comment: Your `render(..)` produces HTML, and now the Ajax call aims to interpret this as JSON.

Comment: It is very strange that you return content *in* the loop, since that means that the loop is done at most once. Furthermore if the queryset is empty, this will error, since it will not produce any results.

Comment: I can see the variables in if condition are containing the values which I passed from HTML page and the condition is satisfying. I used it in loop because if queryset condition matches it should redirect at that moment . Is there any alternative to achieve this ?

Comment: It is a for else loop. Mistakenly I pasted it as  if else . My bad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Create a view to render the template `bot/chatbox.html`.
- Optimize searching for the employee with the given email and password.
- Return a url pointing to the view that you created if the credentials are correct, else return errors.

**Example**:

```
def chatbox_index(request):
    context = {}
    template_name = "bot/chatbox.html"
    return render(request, template_name, context=context)

# add `url(r'chatbox/$', views.chatbox_index, name='chatbox') in app's `urls.py`

from django.urls import reverse

class Login(View):  
    def post(self,request,*args,**kwargs):  
        response_data={}  
        response_data['email']= request.POST['email']  
        response_data['password']= request.POST['password']  

        # optimize searching for employee using Django ORM
        employee = Employee.objects.filter(
            usr_email=request.POST['email'],
            usr_password=request.POST['password']
        ).first()

        if employee is not None:
            response = {"success_url": reverse('chatbox')}
            return HttpResponse(
                json.dumps(response),
                content_type="application/json",
                status=201
            )
        else:
            response = {"errors": "Invalid Credentials"}
            return HttpResponse(
                json.dumps(response),
                content_type="application/json",
                status=401
            )

# ajax callbacks
$.ajax({
    ...,
    success: function(data) {
        if (data.success_url) {
            window.location.href = data.success_url;
        }
    },
    error: function(error) {
        var errors = error.errors;
        // display user the errors
    }
});
```

Comment: Hi Sachin,   Thank you for the response I tried this . However it is not redirecting, it is not calling chatbox_index() function in views.py file I added the redirection url in urls.py file as well.

Comment: Please paste here the value of the `data` from ajax success callback.

Comment: It worked :) Thanks though. I was passing an object and json was not accepting was giving error so I changed the json code.

Comment: Please accept the answer if it worked or suggest edit if necessary.

Comment: I did I wasn't aware of this functionality:)